# Cannot find maven dependencies when importing from another module

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with multiple submodules.

I have a root pom file in which I have the jackson dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the **jackson dependency** in one module called **'api'**.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have a new module named **'client'** in which I import the maven dependency of **'api'**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>abc.com</group>
 <artifactId>api</artifactId> 
 <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using the following command to compile.

```
mvn -Djackson.version=2.4.4 compile
```

I am getting a compile error if I try to import jackson libraries to the client **module** unless I add the **jackson** dependency explicitly again to the **client** module

Why is adding the **api** dependency not sufficient as it already contains the jackson dependency

Answer (score 2):

You define the `jackson` dependency in `api` as `provided`, so it is not transitive:

> **provided**
>   This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, ***and is not transitive***.

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope (emphasis added)

Comment: sorry. I have updated the question. I'm passing the version when I try to compile

Comment: It's not the version missing, it's that the `api`'s dependency on jackson is declared as `<scope>provided</scope>`. Where are you using the root pom? Only `api` or `client` as well?

Comment: I am using the root pom for both api and client. And passing the jackson.version when i compile. Isn't tat sufficient ?